# Rating form is not giving any input fields

Tags: solspace-rating, comment-form

I have tried using standard example template given in Solspace website, its not giving any output other than saying no reviews message.

I have tried rating form tag within channel entries and outside, nothing has worked. In my settings i have allowed guest review as well.

Any idea of what s that missing in my approach. appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

New to this add-on as well and was having the same problem with the example code for the exp:rating:comment_form, couldn't get it to show up, but then started to realize that their larger blocks of example code have some errors, be sure to check the closing tags and syntax against the tag specific examples. Also be sure to enable all users and your intended channel in the Ratings add-on preferences, hopefully this helps.